# How can I filter JSON data using D3 and javascript (TypeError: data.filter is not a function)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm new in D3.js and I've created a Sunburst Zoomable reading the json data.
Everything is OK up to here.

Then I created form-control called "Selecionar-periodo", whith 3 options (Todos, Noturno, Integral)
(pls see image)

And I added in my javascript the appropriate code to filter my data according to which was selected in "Selecionar-periodo" (pls see image and code below)

```
$("#Selecionar-periodo")
    .on("change", () => {
    update()
});

function update() {
d3.json( "data/unicamp_ft.json").then(data => {
        
        const periodo = $("#Selecionar-periodo").val();
        
        const filteredData = data.filter(d => {
            if (periodo === "Todos") return true
            else {
                return d.Periodo == periodo
                }
            });
                
        console.log(filteredData);
```

The expectation was:

- user select the Periodo
- based on this value the code checks if "Selecionar-periodo" = "Todos" (all in english) all data from json will be used, ELSE the code will retrieve the data according d.Periodo = periodo (Noturno or Integral). SO in my dataset there is a field called "Periodo" which be used to filter the data.

but when I execute it I'm receiving the message : *"Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: data.filter is not a function"*

I already checked many documentations where I saw that I could use data.filter as I used.
But now I believe I will need a help from some expert. Please could you help me ?
following my full code and dataset JSON

[Screen-copies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/au6Gk.png)

JSON file --> https://www.dropbox.com/s/ea2bw4121vxp8i1/unicamp_ft.json?dl=0

full code --> https://www.dropbox.com/s/q68sh7ktdolru2m/index.html?dl=0

Comment: If I read the code correctly, `data` is the parsed JSON, which results in an Object/Array depending on how it is defined in the json file. And I believe that your `unicamp_ft` field is an object, not an array? Filter can only be run on arrays; that's why it's complaining.
[Here](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/d3js/loading-data-from-file-in-d3js#d3.json) is the link to the docs where I see it works when the entire JSON has an array

Comment: Hi @M3rr1 , thanks for your answer. It helped to solve the issue. You are right I was referring to Object instead of Array. So I changed the line accordingly mentioning the Array "children" **(data.children.filter)** and it works !  Now I'm facing a second challenge to adapt the sunburst zoomable chart to read the data filtered. Thanks a lot